# Application inside a Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to run an application inside a windows form in VB.net.
I'm able to that if I run application like notepad or calculator.
My target is to run my default email client for sending an email and the application run outside my window form and somethimes gives me this error: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Process has exited, so the requested information is not available".
Is there a way to fix that ?

This is what I've done:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim myProcess As Process = New Process()
Public Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" Alias "SetParent" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As System.IntPtr

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    '
    'myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "mailto:test.mail@gmail.com"
    '
    myProcess.Start()
    myProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
    SetParent(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, Me.Handle)
End Sub
```

End Class

Can someone help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a hack, to put it this way, because it is not supported by the clients you try to "embed".  Anyway, your solution will vary greatly from e-mail client to e-mail client.  It is possible that your e-mail client can be even a browser, and nowadays browsers span multiple processes and the one whose window you see is not necessarily the one you start. Same can go even to Outlook, where you start a process with one main window and the window for the message can be another top-level window whose parent is the desktop.

In your case, perhaps a better idea is to use MAPI.  Check [this](https://github.com/PandaWood/Simple-MAPI.NET) out.

Comment: Hi, I tryed to use MAPI, works but I was not able to run the client inside my form: myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = mapi.Send("Test01", "Note01", True)

Comment: Hi, as I told you, running the client inside your form is not supported by common clients.  You may have partial success, but you are on your luck, and you never know when it will crash.  If you absolutely must have an e-mail client in your app, the best approach is to build the UI and use MAPI for sending the mails.

Answer (score 0):

Your post states that your objective is to

> run my default email client for sending an email.

One thing you could try is invoking **explorer.exe** as the target with a **mailto** link as the argument.

```
Private Sub ButtonSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSend.Click
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", "mailto://dummy.email@google.com")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't works.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, but I must say I'm surprised! Can you tell me what error you get when it executes? How is the default Mail client is set up on your PC in your Settings\Apps\Default Apps\Mail for the `mailto` protocol? If you say it doesn't work I believe you, but it must be giving some kind of hint as to what is going wrong! Of course I made sure it works perfectly on my own PC before posting it as an answer. Thx.